# Why won't my Nacon / Plantronics RIG 800lx headset charge?

Tags: xbox-one, audio-hardware

I have a Rig 800lx headset that I've used for over a year with my xbox one. It worked perfectly but one day it stopped turning on.

I've tried plugging it in to different power adapters and using different micro-usb cables and letting it charge for hours on end but it still wont turn on.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue with the instructions I received from Nacon support via email:

---

Make sure that the device that you are plugging the micro-USB cable into is providing power.

- If you are using a console, check that it is not going into a power-saving mode when shut down.
- For PS4, use Rest Mode instead of turning off your console and check your settings to make sure that power is being provided to your USB ports while the console is in Rest Mode.
- Try plugging in the headset into a USB power adapter that uses power from the wall (AC power).
- NOTE: Make sure that the OUTPUT of the adapter is 5 Volts DC. You can damage your headset for supplying incorrect voltage.

There are two hardware versions of the RIG 800 headset. Please check the microphone boom to determine which version of the RIG 800 headset. If you have a RIG 800 headset with a non-removable boom, please follow these additional steps to start charging your headset:

1. Push the power switch into the "On" position.
2. Make sure the micro-USB cable is plugged into a power adapter.  You can also use the USB port on your console or PC, but a power adapter will have better chances.
3. Plug in the headset with the micro-USB cable.
4. The headset may cycle between "Power On" and "Power Off" voice prompts. This is an expected behavior.
5. Let the headset charge for an hour and unplug it.
6. Check the status of the headset by turning it off and turning it back on. The headset should say "Power On" when powered on.
7. Turn off the headset and plug it back in to continue charging (usually another hour). Your headset is now back to normal operation.

---

I think making sure that the headset is turned on when plugging it in is the key,  and plugging in the microusb with a firm push. After I did that, the headset did what support suggested it might do: cycled between "Power On" and "Power Off" voice prompts, and started charging.

Alternatively, I also found some suggestions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/plantronics/comments/km3q25/rig_800_wont_charge_no_indicator_light_fix/) which may help if the instructions above don't work.